# How to use the += function in a namespace

Tags: c++, syntax, namespaces, overloading

How can correctly use this '+=' function if the function is declared within a namespace?

```
namespace WinFile
{
     std::stack <tstring> operator += ( std::stack <tstring>& s1, std::stack <tstring> s2 )
     {
        // Post:

     if ( s1 == s2 )
     {
       return s1;
     }

        while ( !s2.empty() )
        {
           s1.push( s2.top() );
           s2.pop();
        } 

        return s1;
   }
}
```

Now how do I use this function (**without saying using namespace WinFile**):

```
std::stack <tstring> s1;
std::stack <tstring> s2;
// ...after adding some values to the stacks
s1 += s2;                // this gets a compile error
s1 WinFile::+= s2        // this says its invalid to have a ':' infront of a +=
```

Comment: Is the code that fails inside the same `WinFile` namespace?

Comment: @Jake: You should return a reference and not a value. Also, your second parameter should probably be a const reference instead of a value too (there is no need for this argument to be copied).

Comment: By the way: If the operator+= and one of its argument types reside in the same namespace, no qualification is necessary due to [argument-dependent name lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup). Of course this won't help you since you are not allowed to define your operator+= in the std namespace.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: the second argument can't be a const reference, since there's no way to read a `std::stack` without emptying it. Hence the copy, which I think could be move-optimized if the rhs is a temporary or otherwise movable.

Comment: That is to say, the rhs *could* be a const reference, but you'd need to take a copy anyway to do the `pop`. Ignoring the weird `s1 == s2` check that exits early before there's any need for it to be a copy, and ignoring also any concerns about binary compatibility in case the behavior changes in future to not take a copy: if you're going to make a copy then you might as well do it at the point of taking the parameter, where it potentially could be moved or copy-elided instead of copied.

Comment: @SteveJessop: You are right, I did not think of that. I agree, if you are going to copy anyways, you should do it with a value-parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already suggested you can use a "using" clause:

```
using WinFile::operator+=;
```

or

```
using namespace WinFile;
```

or you can use the function directly with the following code:

```
s1 = WinFile::operator +=( s1, s2 );
```

None of which are particularly ideal, but there are no other ways, to my knowledge, to do it.

Answer (score 4):

In the function that uses `+=`, add:

```
using ::WinFile::operator+=;
```

This will make your operator eligible for consideration. (You can omit the leading `::` if there's no ambiguity.)

Answer (score 2):

The name of an operator function contains the keyword `operator`, and your particular operator is a free function, so the qualified call would be:

```
WinFile::operator+=(s1, s2);
```

I am not sure that this is a sound design anyway, you are (trying) to extend the interface of `std::stack` by adding functions that are not defined in the same namespace of the type --this is somehow against the *interface principle*, and more so, you are adding operators... which are cumbersome to use unless you call them from the same namespace they are defined (or they are brought into scope by a using declaration) or they are defined in the same namespace where the type is defined (so ADL will pick them up). It is probably best to avoid both or at least provide a real name to the function.

On the definition of the operator itself, the semantics are *strange*: if both stacks are equivalent then you do nothing, while if they are different you move all the contents of the second stack to the first one... and then also return a copy! This will probably cause surprises in the future. If what you meant to check is whether they refer to the same object, as the second argument is a copy, it will be impossible (i.e. the caller cannot provide a reference to the copy)

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility - the namespace containing `tstring` is an associated namespace for the purpose of lookups involving `std::stack<tstring>`. So if you can modify that namespace, you could put your `operator+=` in the same namespace as `tstring`. Either define it there, or put `using ::WinFile::operator+=` there.

Obviously that doesn't help you if `tstring` is in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wirte

```
using namespace WinFile;
```

in your implementation file (*.cpp)

Comment: PS dude read the question it EXPLICITY says using a technique other than this

Answer (score 0):

Use Kerrek's solution of `using WinFile::operator+=`, but for completeness, I believe it's possible to do:

```
WinFile::operator+=(s1, s2);
```

I will note that I consider overloading `+=` to mean "push onto a stack" to be in incredibly bad form.

Comment: Personally I don't mind that, other languages have `+=` for containers that means "append", so it makes sense to me. It might be more C++-ish to use `operator<<`. I don't like it returning a copy, though.

Comment: Even C++ `std::string` defines `operator+` and relatives, including `operator+=`, to mean "append."  However, I agree with those who call that a mistake.  For one thing, `4 + 5 == 5 + 5`, but `"std::string("foo") + "bar" != std::string("bar") + "foo"`.  Overloaded operators are functions with special names, names that come largely from math, and I prefer only using those function names when they have the same qualities as their math counterparts.  I'm fine with having an `append()` function or method, I just think it ought to be called `append()`.

Comment: depends what you mean by "math". Non-commutative addition is fairly rare but not unheard of, and of course in C++ it's not associative for floating-point types. Non-commutative multiplication in mathematics is quite common (matrices, quaternions). So the "qualities" of the operators depend a lot on how much abstract algebra you've done. I don't think I've ever seen a bug caused because someone had genuine difficulty remembering that string addition is non-commutative, although perhaps I have seen one and forgot.

Comment: I've never seen a bug caused by it.  I simply agree with Stepanov and Larry Wall on the issue.  I also remember a passage from _The Design and Evolution of C++_ where Stroustrup mentioned originally using `<` and `>` for input/output operations but "the meanings less than and greater than were too ingrained in people's minds" so he switched to `<<` and `>>`.